# Validating emails with firebase for iOS

Tags: ios, email-validation, firebase

When submitting a request to create a new user, if the user tries to submit with an invalid email, the app crashes (I.E. without an @ sign). Is there a way to check if an email is valid through Firebase or is that something I need to validate app side?

The error I get in the console is:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidEmail', reason: 'jfkdsla;fjdk is an invalid email address'

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://myapp.firebaseio.com/users/%@", displayName.text];
    Firebase *dataRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:url];
    [dataRef observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

        NSLog(@"Ref %@", snapshot.value);
        snapshotValue = snapshot.value;
    }];

    if (snapshotValue == NULL) {
        AppDelegate *appDelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        [appDelegate.authClient createUserWithEmail:email.text password:password.text andCompletionBlock:^(NSError* error, FAUser*user) {

            if (error != nil) {
                // Error
                NSLog(@"ERROR CODE: %d",error.code);
                NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",error);

                if (error.code == -9999) {

                    email.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

                }

            } else {

                NSLog(@"Created %@",user.userId);
                Firebase *userRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://myapp.firebaseio.com/users/%@",displayName.text]];
                [[userRef childByAppendingPath:@"name"] setValue:fullName.text];
                [[userRef childByAppendingPath:@"user_id"] setValue:user.userId];

                Firebase *userCredentials = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://myapp.firebaseio.com/users/%@/credentials",displayName.text]];
                [[userCredentials childByAppendingPath:@"email"] setValue:email.text];
                [[userCredentials childByAppendingPath:@"password"] setValue:password.text];



                AppDelegate *appDelegate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

                [appDelegate.authClient loginWithEmail:email.text andPassword:password.text
                                   withCompletionBlock:^(NSError* error, FAUser* user) {

                                       if (error != nil) {
                                           NSLog(@"There was an error logging in to this account: %@",error);

                                       } else {
                                           NSLog(@"logged in");
                                           [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

                                           [appDelegate.window.rootViewController presentViewController:appDelegate.tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];

                                       }
                                   }];                    

            }

        }];

    }
    else {

        displayName.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    }

    }
```

Comment: is there any code or snippet that shows that you do with the *result* from Firebase?  can you also show the code that extracts the text of the e-mail address text field?

Comment: Here is my code for creating a new user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since an exception is being thrown, throw the "`createUserWithEmail`" line of code into a "`@try{} / @catch{}`" block:

```
@try {
    [appDelegate.authClient createUserWithEmail:email.text password:password.text andCompletionBlock:^(NSError* error, FAUser*user) {
        ...
        ...
        // keep that big huge block part intact
        ...
        ...
    }
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: That caught the exception but I don't know how to handle the error. 
Exception: fjdksla;f is an invalid email address
2013-04-03 17:19:36.747 Plate[11487:19703] Ref <null>

Comment: Right now if the snapshotValue or "Ref" = NULL that means the email is not taken so the user can register. The problem I'm having is that if the "Ref" is NULL but the email is invalid, then the app crashes.

Comment: well in there you can probably throw some "`UIAlertView`" or some other alert (e.g. include the message from the server about the invalid e-mail address, which would make it nice for your users).

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense now. I guess I wasn't thinking straight. I can handle the error in the @catch statement. Thanks a lot for your help, Michael!

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. An invalid email shouldn't be crashing the app.  We'll get this fixed in a future version of the library (likely later this month). Keep an eye on [@FirebaseRelease](https://twitter.com/firebaserelease) for announcements about new versions of Firebase libraries.